# creating Writeable[Argonaut.Json] for play framework http response

Tags: scala, playframework, argonaut

I am trying to change the implementation of this function from using plays json library like so

```
def apply[T](action: => ApiResponse[T])(implicit tjs: Writes[T], ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Result] = {
    action.fold(
      err =>
        Status(err.statusCode) {
          JsObject(Seq(
            "status" -> JsString("error"),
            "statusCode" -> JsNumber(err.statusCode),
            "errors" -> Json.toJson(err.errors)
          ))
        },
      t =>
        Ok {
          JsObject(Seq(
            "status" -> JsString("ok"),
            "response" -> Json.toJson(t)
          ))
        }
    )
  }
```

to use argonaut like so

```
def apply[T](action: => ApiResponse[T])(implicit encodeJson: EncodeJson[T], ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Result] = {
    action.fold(
      err =>
        Status(err.statusCode) {
          Json(
          "status" -> jString("error"),
          "statusCode" -> jNumber(err.statusCode),
          "errors" -> err.errors.asJson
          )
        },
      t =>
        Ok {
          Json(
          "status" -> jString("ok"),
          "response" -> t.asJson
          )
        }
    )
  }
```

but I get

> Cannot write an instance of argonaut.Json to HTTP response. Try to
>   define a Writeable[argonaut.Json]

for both the Status{} block and Ok{} block and I got a helpful answer to this problem here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/vBMf72a10Zc

so I tried to create the implicit conversion like so

```
implicit def writeableOfArgonautJson(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[Json] = {
      Writeable(jsval => codec.encode(jsval.toString))
    }
```

which I think converts the json object to a string and provides it to codec.encode which should convert it to Array[Bytes] but I get

> Cannot guess the content type to use for argonaut.Json. Try to define
>   a ContentTypeOf[argonaut.Json]

jsval.nospaces.getBytes also return Array[Bytes] so I dont know if that can be used to help at all

so while I think that last error message means I just need to tell play that it should use content type application.json I also feel like this might be an unnecessary rabbit hole and there should be an easier way to do this.

edit: it wasnt such a rabbit hole as defining the contentType has things compiling at least but I still would like to know if this is correct

Comment: With `.nospaces` returning JSON as string, you can pass it to `Ok(js.nospaces).as("application/json")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question, but to confirm, the `Writable[A]` is:

1. how to convert a type `A` to `Array[Bytes]` and
2. what content type to use in the response, which also requires
3. the current character encoding

The character encoding is taken care of by the implicit `Codec` instance, so you then need an implicit `ContentTypeOf[A]` where `A` is `argonaunt.Json`:

```
implicit def contentTypeOf_ArgonautJson(implicit codec: Codec): ContentTypeOf[argonaut.Json] = {
  ContentTypeOf[argonaut.Json](Some(ContentTypes.JSON))
}
```

and then the `Writable[A]`, which has a [type constraint](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.7/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/http/Writeable.scala#L37) on `A` that there be an in-scope `ContentTypeOf[A]` (which you've just defined):

```
implicit def writeableOf_ArgonautJson(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[argonaut.Json] = {
  Writeable(jsval => codec.encode(jsval.toString))
}
```

And as you point out, there endeth the rabbit hole. And indeed, it certainly seems a bit of a diversion but not much extra code when you consider you can now just do `Ok(myArgonautObject)` in as many actions as you want without further conversion and header-setting boilerplate.

Perhaps you could put those implicits in an `ExtraJsonHelpers` trait and mix it in to your controllers, for more boilerplate reduction.

Comment: Thanks, it didnt turn out as bad as I thought it would.  I guess thats the penalty for stepping out of the framework and using argonaut.

Comment: Might you be able to recommend a good place for me to put those two implicits so that they are available anywhere I might end up trying to return a http response

Comment: Very helpful answer. Was wondering if you could also give us the Reader implicit please to complete the picture?

Comment: @Armin you might be confusing this with `Writes` (how to convert something to JSON), which is different from `Writeable` being used here (how to convert something into a Result)